# MVC call functions method in javascript function How come?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, function

How can I call C# function in JavaScript?

My c# function :

```
@functions{ 
    public List<string> Photo(int PostID)
{
    DataBase.Current.Baglan().Open();
    Objects.Current.Command.Dispose();
    Objects.Current.Command.Parameters.Clear();
    Objects.Current.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostID", PostID);
    Objects.Current.Command.Connection = DataBase.Current.Connection;
    Objects.Current.Command.CommandText = "Select * from PostPhoto where PostID=@PostID";
    var ReadPhotoUrl = Objects.Current.Command.ExecuteReader();
    while (ReadPhotoUrl.Read())
    {
        string PhotoUrl = ReadPhotoUrl["PhotoUrl"].ToString();
        Posts.Current.PostPhoto.Add(PhotoUrl);
    }
    return Posts.Current.PostPhoto;
} }
```

JavaScript : `

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slider_content = document.getElementById('slider');
var image = [];
var i = image.length;
function getImages(id) {
    //my c# function in call ?
}
// function for next slide 
function nextImage() {
    if (i < image.length) {
        i = i + 1;
    } else {
        i = 1;
    }
    slider_content.innerHTML = "<img src=" + image[i - 1] + ".jpg>";
}
// function for prew slide
function prewImage() {
    if (i < image.length + 1 && i > 1) {
        i = i - 1;
    } else {
        i = image.length;
    }
    slider_content.innerHTML = "<img src=" + image[i - 1] + ".jpg>";
}`
```

The intent is to call the function and pass the image to the image array.

I do not know how to ...

Comment: C# executes on server and js executes on client(browser).

Comment: what should I do, what method should I use?

Comment: Make endpoint, expose your function via HTTP, then use AJAX from JS to call it.

Comment: When Ajax is successful, I need to add array the data
Did I get right?

Comment: yep that's pretty much the basic idea. You can find lots of tutorials about using AJAX and JSON data if you search.

Comment: Is there a way to do it professionally, @ADyson?

Comment: what do you mean by "professionally" exactly? You mean high-quality or something? Everyone's definition of that is different. This isn't too complex a task though, so there aren't _that_ many different ways to do it. Start by learning the basic concept first.

Comment: I personally know C # language for 10 years, but things change in MVC. I know that the above example is simple, but since mvc is just starting, I do not know what is simple, what is advanced. If there is a high-quality way to do this, can you give examples from the point of being an educator?
@ADyson